# About generic pointer to char and strict aliasing

Tags: c, char, strict-aliasing

I don't know why the following code works fine, without `gcc` errors (`-fstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-aliasing=1`).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int 
main(void) 
{
    char  n = 42;
    char *p = &n;
    int  *q = (int *)p;

    *q = 10;

    printf("%d|%d\n", *p, *q);

    return 0;
}
```

If I follow the strict aliasing rule:

> **n1570, § 6.5 Expressions**
>
> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue
>   expression that has one of the following types:
>
> — a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>
> — a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the
>   object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective type of the object,
>
> — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
>
> — a character type.

But `*q` does not have a type compatible with `*p`, either a qualified version, either a signed or unsigned type corresponding, either a character type.

So, why is it allowed?

Comment: "— a type compatible with the effective type of the object" - both are integral types, and you don't even loose precision because you're converting from a char to an int.

Comment: This is undefined behavior, `*q` points to a single char's worth of allocated space, you're writing `sizeof(int)`'s worth of data there.

Comment: A character type is `char`, `unsigned char`, or `signed char`: This code does not violate strict aliasing rules due to the last clause. Nevertheless, it has other problems that yield undefined behavior.

Comment: cmaster: as far as I understand, the lvalue expression has `int` type. I can't see anything that allows _objects_ of character type to be accessed through an `int` lvalue.

Answer (score 3):

It is not allowed. The part of the Standard you posted shows through what types are you allowed to alias objects.

The fact that the code compiled doesn't mean it is correct. You are having three problems with the code that make it the program exhibit undefined behavior.

First is that you assigned a char pointer to an int pointer.
Standard doesn't enforce their alignment and representation, so the resulting pointer is not valid.

```
int  *q = (int *)p;
```

Then you interpreted the `char  n` object as an integer, violating strict aliasing.( Note the quote from the Standard in your question ).

```
*q;
```

Finally you wrote an `int` into the memory of the char object (`char  n`), which causes an overflow because the size of an `int` is always larger than size of a `char`.

```
*q = 10;
```

Comment: Can we use `reinterpret_cast` to make it properly aligned?

Comment: @Unheilig This question is tagged with C, which doesn't have reinterpret_cast.

Comment: C(++)orrect. Caffeine-deficiency on my part.

Comment: This seems to be correct, except the second part about strict aliasing: In the last clause of the standard quote, there is an exception precisely for accessing any data via a `char*`, and vice versa. This exception is necessary to allow functions like `memcpy()` to avoid violating strict aliasing rules.

Comment: @cmaster  OP is accessing a char with an int pointer. That is not defined. But in reverse, accessing an int with a char pointer is.

Comment: @2501 I would interpret "shall have its stored value accessed" as meaning read *and* write accesses. In the wording of the strict aliasing rules there is no difference in *how* you get one `int*` and one `char*`, it only talks about using them to access the memory object. The problem with the code this that the memory object is too small to allow access via an `int*`, and that the `int*` is not necessarily aligned correctly; not that it would be forbidden by strict aliasing rules.

Comment: @cmaster Show me where it is defined that you can access a char as an via integer pointer.

Comment: @2501 I have never said that you can access a `char` via an `int` pointer. That does not work because `sizeof(char) < sizeof(int)`. Nevertheless, you are free to generate a char pointer via `char* charPtr = malloc(sizeof(int));`, fill the array with `char` data, cast it to an `int*`, and finally read the data as an `int`. That does not violate any rules that I know off (except rules for good style, that is).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I asked this question a long time ago, but I think I was trying to know whether it was a misunderstanding of the standard or a rather simple example that went through the `-Wstrict-aliasing` warning option (which is supposed to catch "common pitfalls").

Comment: @md5 I stumbled upon it and saw the incorrect answer.

Comment: @cmaster: The character-type exception was never necessary to make `memcpy` work.  What is necessary is to recognize that (1) what should matter isn't whether an lvalue is of the right type, but rather whether it is freshly derived from one of the right type, and that (2) an lvalue which isn't used at all within a particular execution of a function can't possibly alias anything else within that same execution of that function.  Putting those together will allow not just `memcpy` but the vast majority of of other code that would otherwise require `-fno-strict-aliasing`.

Comment: Despite those benefits, however, it would be be easier to process than the present rules while allowing more optimizations than they do [some code might be broken by the additional optimizations and thus require `-fno-strict-aliasing` even though it presently doesn't, but that would be less common than code that presently requires `-fno-strict-aliasing` but would work under "derived lvalue" rules.]